# "Failure sending Mail" error on program

Tags: c#, .net, system.web.mail

my friend gave me a program which runs in his laptop, he coded with system.webmail and C#, that program can send the email in his machine, but when i run and send it out in my machine, the email didn't send and get "Failure Sending Mail", but in his computer, he can send with his internet. But I am still getting error, even i can't ping to SMTP server or telnet. What will be issue, does my ISP ban the port, or ISP firewall ban the port?

I use port 25 and also 587 too. but it doesn't do any different at all.

Comment: It's probably a configuration issue.  Does his program try to send the e-mail through a local SMTP server on his machine, or a remote server?   It could be any number of things, so additional information would be helpful.

Comment: the remote server (SMTP.LIVE.COM) along with authentication; the configuration is fine too. It works in his network (Singapore), but that doesn't work in my PC (US).

Comment: Are you able to authenticate to the server?  Do you have the source code?

Comment: Are you running any virus checkers or firewalls on your PC? Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194978/prevent-anti-virus-to-block-outgoing-email-with-c

Comment: Yes, in his network (Singapore), it authenticates and works, but when i use it in my network(US), i am getting this failure error.

Comment: No, I don't use any anti-virus or firewalls at home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an unfixed bug in System.Mail.SmtpClient where sending mail to a domain-enabled (Exchange) server fails if you cannot domain authenticate, even if username and password would authenticate, but only if you are farther than ~10ms from domain server.

Comment: You know what, I tried to telnet smtp.live.com 25, i can't get connect to it.

Comment: Incidentally, tcptraceroute can be used to locate the offender. If its your ISP, bug them.

Comment: ya, thanks for that, I will try to bug them tonight to resolve the problem :)

Comment: When I bug them, they want me to upgrade the services haha :)

Comment: Do they advertise "an internet connection"? If so, you have a case of false advertising.

Answer (score 0):

I have a same issue before and it turned out that the email provider "Smart Mail" is blocking my email, The solution I simply added the email address at the safe list in my destination email.

Comment: well, i am sending mail to same address as sender email address. in my case, this may not be issues.